# Date validation in asp.net for TO and FROM dates

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, regex

I have select criterion for the to and from dates in asp.net as below.I want to include validation for date format and also for the comaprision. How can i include below requirements in asp.net validations on sub,it button click?

1. If user select either TO or FROM date he must select both means TO and FROM also.
2. If the TO date is less than FROM date error message should be displayed.

[image]

Comment: @Avd to my knowledge `compareValidator` is for exact comparision and `RequiredField` i dont how i can leverage. @V4Vendetta working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the format, use `CompareValidator`

```
<asp:CompareValidator Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" ...
```

To check the end date is after the start, try another `CompareValidator` (this should work - not tested)

```
<asp:CompareValidator Operator="GreaterThan" 
     ControlToValidate="txtEnd" 
     ControlToCompare="txtStart" 
     Type="Date"
```

To check your more complex requirements, use the `CustomValidator`

```
<asp:CustomValidator
```